# Share custom message, link and image on facebook via facebook sharer.php or using FB.api

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I want to implement facebook sharing. I tried using the facebook sharer.php but it no more accepts custom parameters (deprecated by facebook). Also, I saw an option to use the FB.api to post on facebook.

I just want to know the correct syntax for doing this using FB.api where I can share some custom message, image and link.
P.S. - The application that I am working on is Java based and pages are jsp pages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Messages must be 100% user generated, prefilling is not allowed - if that is what you mean with "custom message". That being said, there is the FB.ui share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

It works similar to sharer.php and only takes the URL as parameter. That´s the recommended way, you just need to add the correct [Open Graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags) to the shared URL.

Another possible way to share something is to use the feed endpoint of the user object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#publish

...but you need to authorize the user with `publish_actions` for that, and you have to go through a review process on Facebook before you can go public with that permission. Obviously, you will not get approved if you prefill the message parameter.

More information about sharing in general: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing