# Custom sharing Buttons

Tags: javascript, facebook, sharing, facebook-sharer

I am trying to implement social media sharing buttons on my Website.
I am successfull in implementing the facebook sharing button.

My Code :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Now i can see the share button and i am able to share the required page. When i click the button another modal comes up :[image]

Now i want when a user clicks the share button then a pre defined message should be there in the highlighted area. How can i acheive this here and also in LinkedIn, Twitter and Google+ buttons.

Do i have to use Open Graph Protocol for this? If yes then can anybody post an article regarding this or tell me how can i achieve this using OG.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share custom message, link and image on facebook via facebook sharer.php or using FB.api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523671/share-custom-message-link-and-image-on-facebook-via-facebook-sharer-php-or-usin)

Answer (score 3):

Prefilling the message is not allowed on Facebook, and it´s not possible anyway. You may want to read the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

Comment: But while using uber app, we can share  the referral code with the users using facebook and they have a pre defined message as well.

Comment: just because you see it in some app does not mean it´s allowed. and with the share dialog it´s not even possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

For facebook : open graph will fetch og tags for description  from that link to display description in share popup.

you can set title,description,thumbnail using meta tag like this.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

For twitter: Go through this link see **data-text**.

https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters

Comment: Hi dhruv do i just need to add these tags in the existing code?

Comment: try it i'm sure about  twitter not for facebook.

Comment: he is asking about prefilling the message, not about the open graph tags