# Sharing link with a preset HASHTAG

Tags: facebook, sharing, hashtag

I 'm looking for a way to create a button that allow to share a URL with a hashtag chosen by me.

Is that possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: a hashtag is just part of the message, looks like this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523671/share-custom-message-link-and-image-on-facebook-via-facebook-sharer-php-or-usin which does not have a solution

Comment: you can include the hashtag in the page's description, but that might be confusing unless you tell the user to add it to the message

Answer (score 11):

In the URL you have to use the parameter hashtag.

Ex:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[URL]&hashtag=%23AquiVaElHashtag
```